# Java add bean to different list based on null check

Tags: java, java-8

I  have below code:

```
List<String> successfullLIst=new ArrayList();
List<String> failedList=new ArrayList();

MyBean myBean=saveindb(accountId);
if(myBean!=null){
    successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid());
}else{
    failedList.add(accountid);
}
```

I want to avoid this if loop.can this be done without using if/else  loop as there are already so many if else present  in my code. PLease help

Comment: `myBean!=null ? successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid()) : failedList.add(myBean.getAccountid());` is this meet your demand?

Comment: Thsi one is telling me to assignit to a boolean.I don't need any boolean param here.As i have  boolean status=myBean!=null ? successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid()) : failedList.add(myBean.getAccountid())..this boolean is over haed for me..no use of that..how can i avoid this

Comment: ```failedList.add(myBean.getAccountid())``` will throw null pointer exception as ```myBean``` will be null when this statement will execute. Why do you want to avoid ```if```?

Comment: corrected the code @pcsutar

Comment: Your code is correct and appropriate. Why would you need to avoid use of an `if-else`?

Comment: Tip: I would use [`Objects.nonNull( myBean )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)) for easier reading, instead of `myBean!=null`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 9+

Pass to [`Optional#ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) a [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that calls [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)).

```java
Optional
    .ofNullable(myBean)
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        it -> successfullLIst.add(it.getAccountid()), 
        () -> failedList.add(accountId)
    )
;
```

## Java 8

Alternatively, we can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). The [`List#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)) method returns a `boolean`.

```java
boolean b = 
    Objects.nonNull(myBean) ? 
        successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid) : 
        failedList.add(accountId)
;
```

Comment: ```Optional.ifPresentOrElse()``` internally uses ```if-else```.

Comment: ifPresentOrElse()   is not recognizing as method.Only it is showing ifPresent

Comment: Objects.nonNull(test) ? succ.add(test.getAccountid()) : fail.add(aco);  ->telling not a statement.i dont want to add a local variable @Remo

Comment: @Remo any way to do it by avoiding that boolean variable. ifPresentOrElse  is not getting recognized

Comment: then I think ifPresentOrElse approach may work

Comment: ```Optional.ifPresentOrElse()``` is part of JAVA 9+

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try-catch` to solve your purpose:

```
List<String> successfullLIst=new ArrayList();
List<String> failedList=new ArrayList();

try
{
    MyBean myBean=saveindb(accountId);
    successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid()); //line no. 7
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    failedList.add(accountid);
}
```

If your `myBean` object is `null` then line no. 7 i.e. `successfullLIst.add(myBean.getAccountid());` will throw `NullPointerException`. Then you can add your `accountid` to failed list inside catch block as shown in above example.

Hope this will work!